# MySQL query not taking GROUP BY into account

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having some problem with yet another SQL query.
This query is supposed to return a 'nb_annonces' of 1, since only one of the rows have an 'annonce_dispo_date' which is superior to today.
The same type of query works when I try to get the rows, but in this one when I try to get the number of rows, it returns the number of 'annonce_dispo' as 'nb_annonces'

```
SELECT `annonce`.`id` , CEIL( MAX( price ) * 1.16 ) AS `max_price` , COUNT( DISTINCT annonce.id ) AS `nb_annonces` , COUNT( annonce_dispo.annonce_dispo_id ) AS `nb_dispo`
FROM `annonce`
LEFT JOIN `annonce_dispo` ON ( annonce_dispo.annonceId = annonce.id
AND STR_TO_DATE( annonce_dispo.dispo_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) >= CURDATE( ) )
WHERE (
(
annonce.price * 1.16
) >=0
)
AND (
annonce.visible =1
)
AND (
annonce.completed =1
)
GROUP BY `annonce`.`id`
HAVING (
nb_dispo >=1
)
```

returns

```
id  max_price   nb_annonces     nb_dispo
337     12           19         19
```

Result wanted :

```
id  max_price   nb_annonces     nb_dispo
#   12           2            #
```

The # stands for a number that I don't really care about.

The only row corresponding has 19 'annonce_dispos' superior to today, hence the 19

It seems like it doesn't take the GROUP BY into account ...

What can I do to get the appropriate results ?

edit (after adding DISCTINCT)

Now getting :

```
id  max_price   nb_annonces     nb_dispo
106     16            1          233
337     12            1          19
```

Which is quite coherent, but I want only one row with nb_annonce corresponding to the number of 'annonce' corresponding

## EDIT # TABLE STRUCTURE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `annonce_dispo` (
  `annonce_dispo_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `annonceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dispo_day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dispo_month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dispo_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dispo_date` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `dispo_price` float NOT NULL,
  `disponibility` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unavailable',
  PRIMARY KEY (`annonce_dispo_id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `annonceId` (`annonceId`),
  KEY `dispo_date` (`dispo_date`),
  KEY `disponibility` (`disponibility`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `annonce` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `roomtype` enum('appartment','house','office','loft','garage','chalet','room','couch') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `capacity` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `surface` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `streetnumber` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `streetname` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `adressComplement` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `city` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `departement` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `lifeRulesDescription` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `doubleBedNb` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `simpleBedNb` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `couchNb` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `roomNb` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `bedroomNb` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionsId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smokers` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `pets` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `ecofriendly` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `caution` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `cleaningPrice` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `mainPicLink` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '/',
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `annoncePriceDev` text NOT NULL,
  `priceAfterWeek` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceAfterTwoWeeks` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceAfterMonth` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceWeek` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceTwoWeeks` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceMonth` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `degressive_activated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `completed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `rented` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `activation_mail` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `activated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `price` (`price`),
  KEY `city` (`city`),
  KEY `zipcode` (`zipcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `annonce` (`id`, `userId`, `title`, `content`, `roomtype`, `capacity`, `surface`, `streetnumber`, `streetname`, `adressComplement`, `city`, `zipcode`, `country`, `departement`, `region`, `lifeRulesDescription`, `doubleBedNb`, `simpleBedNb`, `couchNb`, `roomNb`, `bedroomNb`, `optionsId`, `smokers`, `pets`, `ecofriendly`, `caution`, `cleaningPrice`, `mainPicLink`, `price`, `annoncePriceDev`, `priceAfterWeek`, `priceAfterTwoWeeks`, `priceAfterMonth`, `priceWeek`, `priceTwoWeeks`, `priceMonth`, `degressive_activated`, `completed`, `views`, `rented`, `visible`, `activation_mail`, `modified`, `activated`, `created`) VALUES
(106, 17, 'test distance recherche', 'test distance recherche test distance recherche test distance recherche', 'appartment', 1, 33, 0, 'voie de vaise', '', '28825', 69120, '76', '69', '82', '', 1, 0, 0, 1, NULL, NULL, 1, 1, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 13, 'euro', 33, 33, 33, 231, 462, 924, 0, 1, 18, NULL, 1, 0, '2014-02-10 12:06:37', '2014-02-10 12:06:37', '2013-06-19 11:12:51'),
(337, 17, 'sdasdasdasd', 'sdasdasdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdasdasd', 'appartment', 1, 22, 0, 'qweqw', '', '22859', 58110, '76', '58', '26', '', 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, NULL, 1, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 10, 'euro', 22, 22, 22, 154, 308, 616, 0, 1, 19, NULL, 1, 1, '2014-02-10 09:36:26', NULL, '2013-06-28 17:16:30');

INSERT INTO `annonce_dispo` (`annonce_dispo_id`, `userId`, `annonceId`, `created`, `dispo_day`, `dispo_month`, `dispo_year`, `dispo_date`, `dispo_price`, `disponibility`) VALUES
(1207, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 1, 2, 2014, '01/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1208, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 2, 2, 2014, '02/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1209, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 3, 2, 2014, '03/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1210, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 4, 2, 2014, '04/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1211, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 5, 2, 2014, '05/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1212, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 6, 2, 2014, '06/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1213, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 7, 2, 2014, '07/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1214, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 8, 2, 2014, '08/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1215, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 9, 2, 2014, '09/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1216, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 10, 2, 2014, '10/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1217, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 11, 2, 2014, '11/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1218, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 12, 2, 2014, '12/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1219, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 13, 2, 2014, '13/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1220, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 14, 2, 2014, '14/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1221, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 15, 2, 2014, '15/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1222, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 16, 2, 2014, '16/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1223, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 17, 2, 2014, '17/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1224, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 18, 2, 2014, '18/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1225, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 19, 2, 2014, '19/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1226, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 20, 2, 2014, '20/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1227, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 21, 2, 2014, '21/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1228, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 22, 2, 2014, '22/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1229, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 23, 2, 2014, '23/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1230, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:01', 24, 2, 2014, '24/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1231, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:02', 25, 2, 2014, '25/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1232, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:02', 26, 2, 2014, '26/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1233, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:02', 27, 2, 2014, '27/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1234, 17, 106, '2013-06-19 11:33:02', 28, 2, 2014, '28/02/2014', 10, 'rented'),
(1666, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:40', 1, 2, 2014, '01/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1667, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:40', 2, 2, 2014, '02/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1668, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:40', 3, 2, 2014, '03/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1669, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:40', 4, 2, 2014, '04/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1670, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:40', 5, 2, 2014, '05/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1671, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 6, 2, 2014, '06/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1672, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 7, 2, 2014, '07/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1673, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 8, 2, 2014, '08/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1674, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 9, 2, 2014, '09/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1675, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 10, 2, 2014, '10/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1676, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 11, 2, 2014, '11/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1677, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 12, 2, 2014, '12/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1678, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 13, 2, 2014, '13/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1679, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 14, 2, 2014, '14/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1680, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 15, 2, 2014, '15/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1681, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 16, 2, 2014, '16/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1682, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 17, 2, 2014, '17/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1683, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 18, 2, 2014, '18/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1684, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 19, 2, 2014, '19/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1685, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 20, 2, 2014, '20/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1686, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 21, 2, 2014, '21/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1687, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 22, 2, 2014, '22/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1688, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 23, 2, 2014, '23/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1689, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 24, 2, 2014, '24/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1690, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 25, 2, 2014, '25/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1691, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 26, 2, 2014, '26/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1692, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 27, 2, 2014, '27/02/2014', 10, 'available'),
(1693, 17, 337, '2013-07-04 15:20:41', 28, 2, 2014, '28/02/2014', 10, 'available');
```

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Without knowing your database structure and the desired result, it's difficult to help.  Can you post them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add DISTINCT to `nb_annonces`:

Here's the code:

> COUNT( DISTINCT annonce.id ) AS `nb_annonces`

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! Just for information, do you know why the query didn't behave as predicted ?

Comment: Well, I spoke too fast, now it does another strange thing, I'll update my post.